# Issue with 'equals' and 'contains' functions

Tags: java, equals, contains

```
productTypes 
 _id = [1, 2, 3]

p.getId()
 _id = 1
```

Why does this function always return `false`? For instance, if `p.getId() = 1` and `productTypes = [1, 2, 3]`, it should return true, but it doesn't.

```
List<ProductType> productTypes = new ArrayList<ProductType>();

boolean result = productTypes.contains(p.getId()));


public class ProductType 
{

    private int _id;
    private String _name;

    public ProductType(int id)
    {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public ProductType(int id,String name)
    {
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
    }

    public int getId() 
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(int _id) 
    {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getName() 
    {
        return _name;
    }

    public void setName(String _name) 
    {
        this._name = _name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final ProductType other = (ProductType) obj;
        if (this._id != other._id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're checking if it contains the `id`, which will be autoboxed to `Integer`:

```
productTypes.contains(p.getId()));
```

You should send the `ProductType` instead:

```
productTypes.contains(p);
```

Comment: I don't know why, but productTypes.contains(p); does not work.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos are you sure `p` is `ProductType p`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your list contains `ProductType` not integers.
i.e. This would work:
`productTypes.contains( new ProductType( 1 ) );`